# Connect to Redis hosted on GCP as VM instance

Tags: python-3.x, docker, redis, google-cloud-platform

I have a Redis instance hosted on Google cloud platform as a VM, it has an IP address, port and password.

I'm trying to connect to this instance from a dockerized python3 app.

I have `redis` client lib in the requirements.txt file.

the code I'm trying to connect with is:

```
import redis
pool = redis.ConnectionPool(
                   host='redis://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
                   port=6379,`
                   password=PASSWD
                   db=0
        )
cache = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
```

When I try to use the `cache` variable to decrement a value I receive the following exception:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redis://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6379. Name does not resolve.
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to run by removing `redis://` from the host arg and just keeping the IP address as follows:

```
pool = redis.ConnectionPool(
               host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
               port=6379,`
               password=PASSWD
               db=0
    )
```